# Select count of all values in all columns in table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to count the frequency of every entry in all columns in one table.
For example:

```
col_1| col_2 | col_3 | ...
---------------------------
a    | a     |   c   | ...
c    | d     |   e   | ...
g    | d     |   c   | ...
g    | d     |   p   | ...


Expected Result:
count_1| count_2 | count_3 | ...
---------------------------
a (1)  | a (1)   |   c(2)| ...
c (1)  | d (3)   |   e(1)| ...
g (2)  |         |   p(1)| ...
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you put the values in separate *rows* rather than separate *columns*:

```
select 'col1' as which, col1, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by col1
union all
select 'col2' as which, col2, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by col2
union all
. . .
```

The format you have specified is not a particularly "relational" format, because the values on each row are not really part of the same entity.